# How can I pass a variable value from a "page" to "layout" in Nuxt JS?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm a beginner in VUE and donnow this one is the correct syntax. I need the variable {{name}} to be set from a page. Which means I need to change the value of the variable page to page. How can I achieve that? Help me guys. 
My "Layout" Code is like below -

```
<template>
  <div class="login-page">
    <div class="col1">{{ name }}</div>
    <div class="col2">
      <div class="content-box">
        <nuxt />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  props: ['name']
}
</script>
```

And my "Page" code is following -

```
<template>
  <div>Welcome</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  layout: 'login',
  data: function() {
    return {
      name: 'Victor'
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this can be achieved by using the vuex module. The layout have access to the vuex store, so once a page is open, you can call a mutation to set the page name and listen the name state in the layout component.

First the Vuex module, we can add a module by creating a file in the store folder,
in this case we are creating the page module:

```
// page.js file in the store folder
const state = {
  name: ''
}

const mutations = {
    setName(state, name) {
    state.name = name
  }
}

const getters = {
  getName: (state) => state.name
}

export default {
  state,
  mutations,
  getters
}
```

Now we can use the `setPageName` mutation to set the pageName value once a page reach the created hook (also can be the mounted hook):

```
// Page.vue page
<template>
  <div>Welcome</div>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    layout: 'login',
    created() {
      this.$store.commit('page/setName', 'Hello')
    },
  }
</script>
```

And in the layout component we have the computed property pageName (or name if we want):

```
<template>
  <div class="login-page">
    <div class="col1">{{ name }}</div>
    <div class="col2">
      <div class="content-box">
        <nuxt />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    name() {
      return this.$store.getters['page/getName']
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

### And it's done!

Answer to your question in the commets:

The idea behind modules is keep the related information to some functionality in one place. I.e Let's say you want to have name, title and subtitle for each page, so the page module state variable will be:

```
const state = { name: '', title: '', subtitle: ''}
```

Each variable can be updated with a mutation, declaring:

```
const mutations = {
  setName(state, name) {
    state.name = name
  },
  setPageTitle(state, title) {
    state.title = title
  },
  setPageSubtitle(state, subtitle) {
    state.subtitle = subtitle
  },
}
```

And their values can be updated from any page with:

```
this.$store.commit('page/setPageTitle', 'A page title')
```

The same if you want to read the value:

```
computed: {
  title() {
    // you can get the variable state without a getter
    // ['page'] is the module name, nuxt create the module name
    // using the file name page.js
    return this.$store.state['page'].title
  }
}
```

The getters are good for format or filter information.

A new module can be added anytime if required, the idea behind vuex and the modules is to have a place with the information that is required in many places through the application, in one place. I.e. the application theme information, if the user select the light or dark theme, maybe the colors can be changed. You can read more about vuex with nuxt here: https://nuxtjs.org/guide/vuex-store/ and https://vuex.vuejs.org/

Comment: Hi....Thanks. It's worked. As a beginner I have a doubt. For another variable, am I need to create a separate file in store folder?

Comment: Or else please tell me how I can pass multiple variables from a “page” to “layout” here?

Comment: Hi! I added additional information about your question in the answer :D.